effective tensor multiplication in PyTorch
Does anybody know how I can effectively calculate two tensors multiplication - for example, I have two tensors of shapes (15, 256) and (112, 256) and their multiplication to be tensor of shape (15, 112) can be calculated in 7 microseconds. But if I have tensors like A - (15, 100, 256) and B - (112, 2000, 256) and I make something like C = (A.reshape(-1, 256) @ B.reshape(256, -1).reshape(15, 100, 112, 2000).permute(0, 2, 1, 3).max(-1).values.sum(-1) to get tensor of shape (15, 112), it takes 1000 times more time. Can it be calculated faster?
I understand that second calculation should be much larger than first one, but maybe it can take less time than in my implementation

I have no time for more right now, but look at this: https://github.com/dgasmith/opt_einsum

@phipsgabler I don't wanna use unknown libraries such as that

einsum is builtin in pytorch : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html

@Lelouch I tried it, but it is too slow

What kind of hardware are you running on exactly? And what is your data like? There could be different optimizations possible depending on the answers to both of those questions.

@ryanwebjackson I have Nvidia a100 gpu and my data are batch of tensors and this batch shape is [15, 100, 256] and [112, 2000, 256]

@Name understandable, but you don't have to add it as as dependency. If the tensor sizes are known, you can compute the optimal contractions beforehand and just add the appropriate code (a sort of metaprogramming approach). See https://dgasmith.github.io/opt_einsum/getting_started/reusing_paths/.

@phipsgabler the problem is that I use it only once, but it generates large tensor of shape [15, 100, 112, 2000] that takes a lot of memory if we take in attention not only that tensor but also its gradients, optimzators etc
